Unexpected/Unknown EF Core Command Failure
I have a .net core app that sends me an email whenever a system error occurs using Serilog email sink.
The most recent error email was bit of cryptic, I know it's EF, I could not figure out exactly what the error was. It starts with this:

024-05-29 06:52:32.501 -04:00 [Error] Failed executing DbCommand
("12,751"ms) [Parameters=["@p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (DbType =
Int32), @p2='?' (DbType = Int32), @p3='?' (Size = 5) (DbType =
AnsiString), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 30) (DbType =
AnsiString), @p6='?' (DbType = DateTimeOffset)"], CommandType='Text',
CommandTimeout='30']" ""SET NOCOUNT ON; UPDATE [PaidCheck] SET
[StatusId] = @p0 WHERE [PaidCheckId] = @p1; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

Then the following block was repeated 17 times in the email:

"INSERT INTO [StatusLog] ([RefId], [RefType], [StatusId], [StatusName], [Timestamp])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[StatusLogId]
VALUES (@p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);" 2024-05-29 06:52:39.655 -04:00
[Error] Failed executing
DbCommand ("566"ms) [Parameters=["@p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?'
(DbType = Int32), @p2='?' (DbType = Int32), @p3='?' (Size = 5) (DbType
= AnsiString), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 30) (DbType = AnsiString), @p6='?' (DbType = DateTimeOffset)"], CommandType='Text',
CommandTimeout='30']" ""SET NOCOUNT ON; UPDATE [PaidCheck] SET
[StatusId] = @p0 WHERE [PaidCheckId] = @p1; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

It ends with this:
INSERT INTO [StatusLog] ([RefId], [RefType], [StatusId], [StatusName], [Timestamp]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.[StatusLogId]  
VALUES (@p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);"

That's the whole email without any further details. I've never seen an error like this. I mean it's EF failing to execute a command, but where are the parameter values? What's with all the question marks for the parameter values in the first code block? And exactly what's the error?
Thanks for any advice.

Have you enabled sensitive data logging?

I have not. I have enabled it now. Let's see if this error occurs again, thanks @nbokmans!

Have you made any changes to the database manually?

No I have not. The error occurred around 6am this morning. We did a production deploy last night. But that was 8pm. So if this is related to the deploy, it sends me the email 10 hours late. Even if it’s related to the deploy, what’s exactly the error?

Any new triggers on tables? It can be third party tool which creates triggers automatically, for example, for monitoring changes.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv the deploy last night did include new triggers. So you think the error is related to the triggers? I don't have any third-party tool that creates them automatically, it's just my own sql script that added the trigger.

Well, check this Breaking change - you have to tell EF Core that your table has trigger(s).

@SvyatoslavDanyliv i do have that in EF Core dbcontext. It's actually generated by "EF Core Power Tools", I don't really manage the codes. Plus, if I am missing this trigger setting, I would assume this error will occur whole lot more. So far, it's just that once.

If EF Core is generating  OUTPUT for tables with trigger, you have not configured DbContext properly. "EF Core Power Tools" is not official EF Core package and may have this weakness.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for letting me know! I've looked at my generated trigger code, it looks like this:
entity.ToTable(tb =>
{
tb.HasTrigger("PaidCheck_Deleted");
tb.HasTrigger("PaidCheck_Updated");
});
I am little confused about the documentation, does it mean it should be like this?
.ToTable(tb => tb.UseSqlOutputClause(false));
